# flutter-firestore: how to count all elements in all arrays in a map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, count

I am trying to count all elements in all arrays inside a firestore map to get the result of number 3.

[image]

I used the following function to get the result of counting all the elements inside `chatRoomIds` field.

```
int _getUnseenMessagesNumber(List<Map<String, dynamic>> items) {
int counter = 0;
for (final item in items) {
  counter += item.values.first.length;
}
return counter;
}
```

Finally I tried to show the result of counting with the following code.

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('crews')
                          .doc(uid)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        int number = _getUnseenMessagesNumber(
                            snapshot.data['chatRoomIds']);
                        if (snapshot.data['chatRoomIds'] == null ||
                            number == 0) {
                          return null;
                        } else {
                          return Center(
                              child: Text(
                                number.toString(),
                          );
                        }
                      })
```

When I tried the above code, I got an error saying `type '_internalLinkedHashMap <String, dynamic> ' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>> '`.
What is to be fixed to avoid this error and get the result that I intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is build first a model, I use json serializable for generate the model:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'chat_rooms_ids_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ChatRoomsIds{
  List<PropertyOne> propertyOne;
  List<PropertyTwo> propertyTwo;
ChatRoomsIds({this.propertyOne, this.propertyTwo});
 factory ChatRoomsIds.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ChatRoomsIdsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ChatRoomsIdsToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class PropertyOne{
   String attributeOne;
PropertyOne({this.attributeOne});
factory PropertyOne.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PropertyOneFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PropertyOneToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class PropertyTwo{
   String attributeOne;
   String attributeTwo;
PropertyOne({this.attributeOne, this. attributeTwo});
factory PropertyTwo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PropertyTwoFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PropertyTwoToJson(this);
}
```

this model you can auto generate with the command:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Now, in your code, you can implement the model, like this:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('crews')
                          .doc(uid)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                       
                      if (snapshot.exists) {
                         var propertyOne = <PropertyOne>[];
                         (snapshot.data()['propertyOne'] as Map).forEach((_, value)){
  propertyOne.add(PropertyOne.fromJson(value));
}
                          return Center(
                              child: Text(
                                propertyOne.first.attributeOne.toString(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      })
```

Comment: Thanks victwise. I don't understand what code, status, detail... means. Would you explain about the model with my case? I have a field name 'chatRoomIds' and arrays inside it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.